# Progress Bar in Session Scope showing last progress initially

Tags: session, primefaces, progress-bar

In my facelet, I am working with a progressbar. Now the progressbar's progress is coming from a Holder class which is in SessionScope and my backing bean is in RequestScope. Once the progress is 100% and my activity is finished, what I am doing is setting the progress to 0. Now next time again within the same page when I am clicking on the export button, progress is showing first to 100% and then going down to 0 and then showing actual progress.

My question is when I set the progress is 0 already then why second time initially it is displaying 100 as the value? Any help.

Code is:

```
<p:commandLink id="excelExport"
                        actionListener="#{studentDetailsBean.export}" ajax="false"
                        onclick="progressDisplay.show();">
                        <p:graphicImage library="img" name="excel.png" width="20" />
                    </p:commandLink>
                    <p:tooltip for="excelExport" value="Export to Excel"
                        showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />

                    <p:dialog id="progress_dialog" dynamic="true"
                        onShow="pbAjax.start();pbAjax.setValue(0);" width="300" position="center"
                        widgetVar="progressDisplay" resizable="false" draggable="false"
                        modal="true" showHeader="false">

                        <p:progressBar id="progressBar" widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true"
                            value="#{studentDetailsBean.progressBarHolder.progress}"
                            labelTemplate="Exporting..." style="margin-bottom:0;"
                            interval="2000">
                            <p:ajax event="complete"
                                listener="#{studentDetailsBean.onProgressComplete}"
                                oncomplete="pbAjax.cancel();progressDisplay.hide()" />
                        </p:progressBar>
                    </p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once rendered, the progress bar relies on a javascript object that checks the model repeatedly for modifications.

When it reaches the 100%, the javascript object stops checking the managedbean and preserves it's former state.

When you start another process, the components remains on 100% until it does the first progress checking.

To guarantee that the javascript object (accessible through  widgetVar) will start on 0, you will need to do as fallows (from [Primefaces Demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/progressBar.jsf)):

**XHTML**

```
<p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" value="#{progressBean.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%" styleClass="animated">  
        <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{progressBean.onComplete}" update="growl" oncomplete="startButton2.enable()"/>  
</p:progressBar>

<p:commandButton value="Start" type="button" onclick="pbAjax.setValue(0); PF('pbAjax').start(); PF('startButton2').disable();" widgetVar="startButton2" />
```

**NOTE**: `pbAjax.setValue(0);`